# Pass rest resource output format in url

Tags: rest, format, url-design

AFAIK every resource have a url in REST design. for example `/user/28` is url of user with id equal to 28 and `/users` will return all users.

There are some way to represent output format of the resource:

- passing a query parameter like `format`
- specify it using extensions(changing `/users` url to `/users.json` to get the users in json format)
- specifying the requested format(xml, json, xls, ...) by setting `Accept` http header.

I search the web and it seems the correct way is setting `Accept` header.
But if you want to have a http link (specified by href) to download list of users in xls format, you can't!Also if you want to download the xls by the browser, you will encounter many problems(you should use ajax so the xls should download using ajax and etc.)

If it is the best way, what is the solution for download link and if its not, which solution is better?

Comment: You should read the HTTP standard. If you can have any alternative solutions instead of the accept header, it will tell you. If you find that it is not mandatory to use the accept header, then you can bind a new URI to the resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Accept` header is considered 'more correct', but there are plenty examples of all the options you mention.  As far as I can tell, none of them is considered "bad".  Personally, I'd say that you should honor and prefer the `Accept` header, but a `format` query parameter should override it, if present.  The downside of the 'extension' method is that each format results in a different resource, which can get ugly.